# DNS CNAME record - connection was reset

Tags: domain-name-system, connection, cname-record

I am quite new to DNS and have set up a CNAME record for a new domain that I have bought pointing at subdomain.domain2.com.

When I put in my URL http://www.domain1.com I get

> The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while
>   the page was loading.

What could be the cause of this? I cannot see how to get it working. There are currently A Records set up for

"" - blank
*
ftp

mail

Do I need to delete some of these?

Comment: Before you put the URL into your browser, check that you are getting the correct DNS replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's resolving the DNS address fine, but the webserver on that address doesn't recognize the name "www.domain1.com". You need to change its configuration so that it knows that it's serving that name.

Comment: Thanks for the info, could this be because I'm on shared hosting? Is there any easy way to configure this?

Comment: Not without getting the maintainer of your shared hosting to help. The web browser includes the domain name in its requests to the server (in the `Host` header). The server uses that header to decide which site should receive the request. If it doesn't recognize the name, it will do something by default. It sounds like your shared hosting server's default action is to reject the request. You'd like it to look up the CNAME record. It's easier to add the domain name to its configuration.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help - I didn't really know what I was doing with it, so all very useful. Will investigate further.